# How do I drag down a pattern over 100,000 rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

In MS excel, suppose I have a worksheet with over 100,000 rows. How do I use the dragging feature over all the rows from the top for a fixed column efficiently instead of dragging down and waiting a long time for it to reach the bottom?

This is different from just highlighting where I can highlight the first entry, go down to the bottom and then hold shift then click on the bottom box to highlight them all.

Comment: Is the goal to put the same `value` in all the cells?  Do you have a value in the first `cell` that you wish incriment?

Comment: They are different values. I want to drag down the pattern.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to acomplish?

Comment: e.g. e1=if(and(a1<10,b1<100),month(c1),month(d1)). Drag down column e.

Comment: So down columns, not across rows? How many cells is the patter (if it stats at e1 where is the last cell of the pattern?

Comment: yes down column. about 100,000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do this by copying the cells that contain the pattern. Then click in the address bar and enter the range you want to fill down.

Not tried it but I believe it should work.

UPDATE: Select the first cell of the series, click in the address bar and extend the single cell to a range. E.g. start with cell b2, edit the address to b2:b100000. Press enter to accept the range. Then click on the "Fill" menu which is on the HOME tab under Editing (at the right hand side). Choose Series for the fill type and then "Autofill". That works correctly.

Comment: Is the address bar the spot to the left of the f_x? I'm not sure what to put there. I can't put e.g. e1:e100000.

Comment: Yes, that's right. You may be trying to put too big a range in. Unfortunately though it doesn't quite work as expected. I can make a single number fill down but not the pattern.

Comment: Worked it out! . I just tried it with Excel 2013 and successfully filled down 100,000 rows

Answer (score 4):

If you already have cells in the column to the immediate left or right of where you want to fill your pattern, you can select your pattern and then double click the handle at the bottom right of the selection. Excel will autofill your pattern down as far as you have continuously filled cells to the left or right.

For example, double-clicking the handle in this case will autofill the days of the week down to the cell containing `10`.

[image: autofill]

Comment: This filled 31 rows for me. I had to move my formula to another column, do this trick (filling up my 10k rows), then move the results to the column where I wanted it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this VBA to do this. You will have to change what your source cells and destination cells will be.

```
Sub Auto_Fill()

Range("A1:A5").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A100000"), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you can select your range, your question is just how to distribute the formula. Here are two easy ways I use frequently.
  - if your formula is already entered in the first row: Select your range containing also the formula and press 'CTRL+D'.
  - If you haven't yet entered your formula: Select your whole range and enter your formula just as you'd write it in the first cell, but when ready press 'CTRL+ENTER' instead of just ENTER